# I can not see partner user option when i create user

Tags: user, partner

We are have a new guy in a company and i wanna create salesforce partner account for him, i checked i have a remaining licence for partner account.

[image: Remaining Licence]

But when i want to create partner account i cant not see option

[image: User licence options]

How i can see whats wrong ?

Comment: Have you created Account and contact to create community user? Please follow step 1 and 2 of https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_create_external_users.htm&type=5 this article. It seems like you are trying t create partner user directly from user setup.

Comment: Yeah now i saw this document i guess its can help me thanks